# Dual Boot windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.10 grub error

Tags: 12.10, grub2, dual-boot, windows-8

I recently purchased a new HP Laptop with `Windows 8` pre-installed in it.
Then I installed `ubuntu 12.10` from a bootable usb-stick.
Now when I restarted my Laptop, instead of showing `grub` menu in which I have choices to pick which OS to run, it straightaway booted Windows.
Then again I inserted usb with ubuntu 12.10 in it, and ran `boot-recovery` software. It gave me this [url](http://paste.debian.net/236709).
Now when I restarted, grub menu was displayed, and I could run ubuntu from it.
But when I chose windows 8 from the menu, I got an error that it could not find some efi file and returned to grub menu.
Then again I inserted usb, ran boot-recovery software, and restarted, and it gave me this [url](http://paste.debian.net/236772), but this time, it didn't even shown grub menu, it straight booted the windows 8.
I don't know what to do so that grub menu is proper and I could boot both OS.
I have spent whole day on searching and trying various things, but I didn't get the expected results.
Also, while searching on net, I found this some UEFI issue (I don't know about it technically).
So is it windows 8 problem or hardware problem ? If I install `windows 7`, then can I properly install `ubuntu 12.10` on that ?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu 12.10 did you install? 32 or 64-bit?

Comment: @nerof61 : 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

Windows8 uses UEFI boot, so you should follow the advice of the 1st paragraph of the Ubuntu Community Doc about UEFI: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI